# Slack - how to post a link to network folder?

Tags: slack-api, slack

I'm using a webhook to post messages to Slack via PowerShell script and I'd like to include a link to a network folder. I was able to do it with

```
    <file://server/folder|files>
```

however when the generated 'files' link is clicked nothing happens. Is there a way to specify target so that a clicked link opens in a new window? If I copy the generated link and paste it into the browser, the index is rendered just fine and that would be sufficient for my purposes. Are there any alternative solutions?

Comment: The most I've gotten was the ability to send links in that same format `<file://server/folder|files>` and then I have to right-click the link in slack and select "open link". Clicking on the links do nothing for me as well.

Comment: Powershell so probably Windows, what is your default browser and does it matter? Also is the behaviour any different between file: and HTTP:

Answer (score 0):

You may have some success with [Slack's Link Buttons](https://api.slack.com/docs/message-attachments#attaching_link_buttons_to_a_message), which specifically open links in new browser tabs when clicked.

```
{
    "text": "Test Link Buttons",
    "channel": "C061EG9SL",
    "attachments": [
        {
            "fallback": "Test link button to file://server/folder",
            "actions": [
                {
                    "type": "button",
                    "name": "file_request_123456",
                    "text": "Test",
                    "url": "file://server/folder",
                    "style": "primary",
                    "confirm": "Really?"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

[Slack Message Builder example](https://api.slack.com/docs/messages/builder?msg=%7B%22text%22%3A%22Test%20Link%20Buttons%22%2C%22channel%22%3A%22C061EG9SL%22%2C%22attachments%22%3A%5B%7B%22fallback%22%3A%22Test%20link%20button%20to%20file%3A%2F%2Fserver%2Ffolder%22%2C%22actions%22%3A%5B%7B%22type%22%3A%22button%22%2C%22name%22%3A%22file_request_123456%22%2C%22text%22%3A%22Test%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22file%3A%2F%2Fserver%2Ffolder%22%2C%22style%22%3A%22primary%22%2C%22confirm%22%3A%22Really%3F%22%7D%5D%7D%5D%7D)

Comment: I tried this but it looks like it has the same behavior.  You need to right-click the button and say "Open Link"